# Jquery Parsing JSON says undefined

Tags: jquery, json

In my Jquery success fn, when I do this console.log(data);

I am getting,

```
 [
  "{\"name\":\"android\"}"
]
```

When I tried to retrieve name like this data.name[0], I am getting undefined.

I also tried data[0].name, still says undefined.

Comment: thats because data[0] is a string, not an object, thats what the console.log says

Comment: can you show the code with which you generate the json code, because i think your error is there

Comment: Looks like you have an array with a string which contains JSON data.

Comment: u get the data with slash?

Comment: @AJ: The inner quotation marks must be escaped, otherwise it would be invalid.

Comment: @FelixKling: And the double quotes after and before the square brackets? Are they valid? cos wen I removed that it works fine as I posted in my answer

Comment: @AJ: Of course it is correct. If this is JSON, then you have a JSON encoded array with one element, which is a string and contains JSON itself. It is unusual and of course it would be better if the element was an encoded object, and not a string, but it is *valid*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This yields the value:

```
    var data = '[{\"name\":\"android\"}]';
    eval("data=" + data);
    alert(data[0].name);
```

OR

```
    var data = '[{\"name\":\"android\"}]';
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    alert(data[0].name);
```

Can you post the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the array value which is in string to JSON and then parse.

```
var json = JSON.parse(data[0]);
json.name;
```

Comment: this seems right, but i think instead of using this workaround, he should fix his ajax response so that it outputs proper json

Comment: *"First convert the array value to JSON"*: What does that mean? Why convert something to JSON and back again? What you posted "works" but the description does not seem to fit.

Comment: It's still confusing. Maybe it's a terminology misunderstanding. JSON is a textual data format, like XML. Everything the OP has to do is *parsing* the JSON into nativ objects/arrays, at no point they have to *create* JSON. The string *contains* JSON.

Comment: JSON can be converted to a string using `JSON.stringify`.  The example given shows a string, not JSON.  Using JSON.parse converts the string back to JSON, so that it can be parsed as an object.  In fairness, the example shown is incorrect as it's an array of strings.

Comment: @Archer: No, that is incorrect. A JavaScript object or array can be converted *to* JSON with `JSON.stringify`. JSON can only exist in JavaScript in strings. Hopefully helpful: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is like XML, it's a textual data format. You can parse it into native language data types and convert native data types to JSON (just like you can parse XML as DOM and vice versa).

Comment: @FelixKling Cool - thanks for today's new thing learnt.  So what I said was mostly correct, but I was wrong about when the data is JSON and when it's not.  Thanks :)